# How does AC work with dry cell batteries?

Tags: circuit-analysis, non-linear

The "[Tucker Telephone](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tucker_Telephone)" is commonly described as an old-fashioned telephone hand-crank electric generator (AC) "wired in sequence with two dry cell batteries," in order to deliver a powerful electric shock. I don't understand how this circuit could possibly do anything of the sort, and I cannot find a schematic of it anywhere. Even the museum exhibits showing it off do not include dry cells (just the generator and wires.) How  is it wired, and what function do the dry cells serve?

From the research I've done, the generator is likely to produce 40-90 volts AC at 20-30Hz. The dry cell batteries are going to supply DC voltage and not do well with reverse polarity, so what do they do and how are they not damaged? Perhaps more significantly, **why use two** batteries?

#### Why use two batteries?

Dry cells are nominally 1.5 volts, and, as you probably know, if you connect them in series, you get a higher voltage. For example, if you connect 4 cells in series, you get 6 volts output. Dry cells (and other kinds of batteries) are available in a wide range of voltages, which are achieved in just this way. For example, if you take apart a standard "lantern" battery, you will see that it is just 4 D cells wrapped in a bigger package.

[image: Lantern battery cutaway]

I've seen standard dry cells at voltages up to 90 volts (a "B" battery for an antique radio receiver), so connecting two 1.5v or even two 24v batteries in series does not seem necessary when you could just get a higher voltage battery to begin with. And boosting 90 volts (from the generator) by 3 volts (if you connected two 1.5v batteries in series) does not seem worthwhile since you can increase the voltage by more than that just by cranking the generator faster. So **it doesn't make sense to me that you would need two batteries unless you are going to connect them in reverse polarity** (e.g. positive to positive). But then what kind of circuit is that?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fcGi30.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

What kind of waveform does this generate across the load? What is the point of having the dry cells? The simulator basically ignores them, presumably because it uses a very simple model to simulate them. Obviously ideal power supplies would just cancel each other out, but is there something about the non-ideal nature of the batteries that provides some significant effect? If not, what else explains why all the descriptions of the device say it used two batteries in series?

### Edit: Alternate reason for two batteries

Perhaps the reason for using two batteries *was* to increase the voltage supplied. Although I found 90v dry cells powering tube-based radio receivers, I don't know how common they were in the place and time period of the Tucker Telephone (1960s USA), but certainly 6v lantern batteries would have been around. If the batteries were in series to boost the voltage, what kind and voltage battery would likely have been used? Would there have been any benefit from wiring up two 1.5v batteries in the circuit? (Telephones were powered by a pair of 1.5v #6 batteries, so they would have been around and associated with the telephone, but I don't see how it would help. Maybe it did not help but was done anyway, out of ignorance.)

Also, any reference material showing the actual schematic and/or type of batteries used would be appreciated.

Comment: The batteries (calling them "dry cells" is incorrect, because they have more than one cell each) are pointless here; they have no effect if assumed to be ideal.

Comment: Pseudoscience is a well-known word: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudoscience, but this circuit qualifies as "pseudoengineering," a needed neologism. As you state, two 90 VDC sources, *reversed* in series, would just act as a current limiter, due to internal resistance.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik:  There was no engineering done on the "Tucker telephone."  It was the invention of some sadistic bastids at the [Tucker prison in US state of Arkansas.](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tucker_Telephone)  The people involved weren't engineers, but you needn't be one to know that voltages add, and how.  The louder screams of the victims of the Tucker telephone with batteries would be all the experimental results needed to recognize the results of the added voltages.

Comment: @JRE, you misunderstand the comment: the batteries shown in the **schematic diagram** are **oppositely** polarized: 90 V minus 90 V = 0 V. There is no reference to what a "Tucker telephone" is,  only a schematic diagram. Perhaps the schematic shown is *wrong*, but the polarity shown makes no sense.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik: I understand quite well that the schematic in the question is incorrect.  It is based on Sara's misconception about which way around the batteries go.

Comment: Ahh yes. The telephone generator was one of my childhood toys. Together with a rectifier, a flat circular aluminum box (came as packaging material of some cosmetic creme) and a 20uF capacitor if memory serves. Isolate the two halves of the aluminum shell, and put the capacitor inside. I believe I measured up to 150V DC on the cap, depending on how hard I'd crank. Ohh the fond memories of a childhood mischief... About 40 years ago. P.S.: just make sure you don't ever touch the wires while cranking. (ouch.) Gave me a hands-on idea of how voltage and surface area combine together.

Comment: I would guess they probably just pass AC, as a big capacitor would. Not *good* (probably!) for the batteries, but also probably not that bad. We have engineering rules now to make the best possible devices; back when they had telephones with cranks, they were a lot more loose and "if it works, ship it". Heck, for all I know about electrochemistry, maybe it actually is good for the batteries (compare: desulfation). Did you know nonrechargeable batteries can be recharged? Some only slightly, others can take several full recharges.

Comment: (I don't know what happens inside a non-rechargeable battery when you recharge it, but I bet chemists do. Battery makers certainly don't guarantee what will happen. So you shouldn't do it if you want any sort of reliability. That doesn't mean you *can't*.)

Answer (score 1):

Your assumption that the batteries would be connected positive terminal to positive terminal (or negative to negative terminal) is incorrect.  As you've found, that does nothing for you.  It doesn't even limit the current because the internal resistance of lantern batteries is very low - they are used to deliver several amperes of current to large lanterns.

You'd put the batteries in a series circuit.  Negative pole to positive pole.

The voltages add that way.  The voltage also adds with the AC from the generator.

Here's the circuit of just the ring generator and a person:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2firwuY.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Here's what the voltage looks like:

[image]

That's about 250V peak to peak.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fNrtVl.png)</sup>

This is the voltage waveform:

[image]

The peak to peak voltage stays the same, but the whole thing is shifted up.  It spends more time forcing current in one direction through the victim's body.  If you add enough batteries, then there's always current flowing in one direction through the body.

How much that adds to the pain is something you can only answer by experiment.   It comes down to how the body, nerves, and muscles react to different voltages.

At the Tucker prison, somebody did that experiment and found that a couple of batteries (of whatever voltage) added in series made enough "improvement" for it to become part of the "Tucker telephone."

---

[The "Tucker telephone" was a torture device used in the Tucker prison in the US state of Arkansas.](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tucker_Telephone)

The device was nothing more than the hand cranked "ring generator" from an old fashioned telephone with a battery in series.  The ring voltage from such a generator is over 90V RMS, close to that of the typical US wall outlet voltage of 120VAC.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think the batteries were significant in this perverse application. Whoever was observing this was probably not an engineer. Batteries were a part of some standard old-school telephones, wired in series exactly as described. Here is a schematic from [this](https://www.cool386.com/magneto/magneto.html) site:

[image]

It looks to me like you'd get the magneto voltage at L1/L2 with the phone on the hook regardless of the batteries (1.7 uF capacitor in series). With the receiver off the hook you'd only get 3 V (with some components in series) which will have no effect on the torture victim.

The batteries were something like two of these 1.5 V batteries wired in series (image from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_battery_sizes#Round_single-cell)):

[image]

Those batteries were actually still in use for getting model airplane glow plugs started when I was a boy (hence the 'ignition' name on the battery).

The ringing voltage was generated by a [magneto](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telephone_magneto), which uses permanent magnets and generates an AC voltage. Ringing voltage is typically in the 70-90 VAC range, so quite capable of causing pain in the unfortunate prisoner, especially if connected to a sensitive or moist/moistened area of skin.

[image]

Comment: In the normal telephone, the battery provides power for the microphone and speaker while the handset is off-hook, and it is not in series with the magneto. In the schematic you provided, terminal 1 is common, the magneto is across 1 and 3, and the battery is across 1 and 4. Terminals 3 and 4 are DC isolated, coupled only by a transformer.

Answer (score 0):

The ringer of an old telephone operated from 90VAC as shown on your schematic. When the phone was answered or began a phone call the microphone and speaker operated from
about 10VDC.

Comment: I don't think this has anything to do with the torture device that's being asked about.